# git merge branch into master without the changes from parent branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have three git branches: master, A and B. A is based on master and B is based on A. Is it possible to merge B into master without the changes from A?

Answer (score 3):

"git rebase -i" with manual commit drop does the job, but there's even simpler command:

```
git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream> <branch>
```

In your case you want to change "B", so `<branch>`=B, the cut-off point `<upstream>`=A, and your target `<newbase>`=master, so you run:

```
git rebase --onto master A B
```

After that your B branch will only have commits added after it was forked from A.

Finally you can merge B to master as usual.

It is destructive, so it is wise to make a B backup first:

```
git branch B-backup B
```

Comment: i didn't know about --onto, it's far more elegant and simple!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can but not without re-writing git history which can lead to issue on shared branch. So before doing so assure yourself that you won't block anyone work, or worst delete it. To do it you'll have to use [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Let's say your history looks like

```
              -- D  branch-b
             /
     -- B -- C       branch-a
    /
A --                master
```

A, B, C and D representing your commits.

You'll have to do

```
git checkout branch-b #go on branch-b
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

A bit of explaining on the second line:

`git rebase` is you used to perform operations like squashing, deleting and rewriting commits to reapply them on another targeted commit.

`git rebase -i HEAD~3` will allow you to rewrite the last 3 commit from the **HEAD** of `branch-b` to the one just before. You can also use the id hash of the targeted commit.

It will open you the configured text editor you have and it should look like

```
pick aaaa111 Commit B message
pick aaaa222 Commit C message
pick aaaa333 Commit D message
```

Change the `pick` word by `drop` or comment the line of the commit you want to drop both works the same.

```
#pick aaaa111 Commit B message # Comment the line will make rebase drop the commit
drop aaaa222 Commit C message  # Replacing the pick by drop will also
pick aaaa333 Commit D message
```

Save and quit the editor. You'll probably have conflict to resolve to put files in the state you want. You can abort the rebase operation at any moment with `git rebase --abort`. Once you have resolved conflict do

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

Until rebase is completed. And your history will look like

```
      ----- D'      branch-b
     /        
     -- B -- C      branch-a
    /
A --                master
```

Not that the commit on `branch-b` is named D' because rebase will recreate a new commit with the changed and not use the first one.

Don't forget that rebasing will put your local history out of sync with remotes ones and can cause issues when you'll have to share that branch.

Answer (score -2):

No, It's not possible since when you cut a branch B out of A, Its will have all the commits and changes in B.